# Prove discontinous using a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by

$f(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    1 & : x > 3\\
    2 & : x \le 3
  \end{array}
\right.
$

Prove $f$ is discontionus at $x=3$.

Although there are multiple methods for proving discontinuity, I need to show a sequence $a_n \rightarrow 3$ but $f(a_n)$ does not go to $f(3)$.

I cannot find a sequence to satisfy this.

Comment: Use, say, $3+\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_n=3+\frac{1}{n}$

Obviously, $a_n\to3.$

However, $a_n>3\forall n$, that is $f(a_n)=1\forall n$

Thus, $f(a_n)\to1$ since it's a constant sequence.

Also, $1\neq f(3)$.

QED.

Answer (score 4):

While an answer was already provided, I would like to further explain how one would get to the answer. The thought train caould go something like this:

1. OK, I need a sequence $a_n$ that converges to $3$. I want $f(a_n)$ to not converge to $f(3)$.
2. Well, $f(3) = 2$. Therefore, I want $f(a_n)$ to converge away from $2$.
3. Since $f$ only takes two values, I guess I need to find to find $a_n$ such that it converges to $1$, the only other value.
4. $f(a_n)$ will converge to $1$ if all values $f(a_n)$ would be $1$...
5. Where could I find values $a_n$ such that $f(a_n)$? Oh, look! If $a_n$ is larger than $3$, then $f(a_n)$ will be $1$! And I see that no matter how close to $3$ the value is, as long as $a_n>3$, I will have $f(a_n)=1$.
6. I can get arbitrarily close (from above) to $3$, but never reach it!
7. OK, so the conclusion is that I can find a decreasing sequence that converges to $3$ but is always larger than $3$. That's just what I need!

Answer (score -1):

Determine the preimage of $]3/2,5/2[$.  You'll find that is is not open.